# EWS how do I create a Searchfolder in my own mailbox?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I use following Code to Create a SearchFolder but as it gets to the "Save" line it throws following error:

> The email address associated with a folder Id does not match the
>   mailbox you are operating on.

```
private SearchFolder CreateSearchFolder( string email, SearchFilter filter)
{
    ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP1);
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("mailboxworker", "password");
    service.AutodiscoverUrl(email);

    FolderId folderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, new Mailbox(email));

    FolderId searchFolderId = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.SearchFolders, new Mailbox(email));

    // Create the folder.
    SearchFolder searchFolder = new SearchFolder(service);
    searchFolder.DisplayName = "Folder of " + email;

    searchFolder.SearchParameters.SearchFilter = filter;
    // Set the folder to search.
    searchFolder.SearchParameters.RootFolderIds.Add(folderId);   

    // Set the search traversal. Deep will search all subfolders.
    searchFolder.SearchParameters.Traversal = SearchFolderTraversal.Deep;
    // Call Save to make the EWS call to create the folder.
    searchFolder.Save(searchFolderId);

    return searchFolder;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try removing the `searchFolderId` code and just pass `WellKnownFolderName.SearchFolders` directly to the Save `searchFolder.Save(WellKnownFolderName.SearchFolders)`

Comment: I already tryed this. Unfortunately it gives back the same error.

Comment: @MadDev the FolderId doesn't have an overload for a email parameter as a string, `MailBox` object only.

Answer (score 1):

> **associated with a folder Id does not match the mailbox**

All the times I've bumped into this I've fixed it using the Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data `WellKnownFolderName` enum instead of a string folderId

Here is a working example from MSDN: [Create a search folder by using the EWS Managed API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-work-with-search-folders-by-using-ews-in-exchange)

> This example assumes that the ExchangeService object has been initialized with valid values in the Credentials and Url properties.

```
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

static void CreateSearchFolder(string email)
{
    // Create the folder.
    SearchFolder searchFolder = new SearchFolder(service);
    searchFolder.DisplayName = "From Developer";
    // Create a search filter to express the criteria for the folder.
    EmailAddress developer= new EmailAddress("Jeremy@stackoverflow.com");
    SearchFilter.IsEqualTo fromManagerFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(EmailMessageSchema.Sender, developer);

    // Set the search filter.
    searchFolder.SearchParameters.SearchFilter = fromManagerFilter;
    // Set the folder to search.
    searchFolder.SearchParameters.RootFolderIds.Add(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox);
    // Set the search traversal. Deep will search all subfolders.
    searchFolder.SearchParameters.Traversal = SearchFolderTraversal.Deep;
    // Call Save to make the EWS call to create the folder.
    searchFolder.Save(WellKnownFolderName.SearchFolders);
}
```

Here is another example on MSDN [Creating search folders by using the EWS Managed API 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633687(v%3Dexchg.80))

Comment: I previously suggested this in my opening comment and OP said it didn't help

Comment: @MadVev you deleted your 2nd comment. Which now takes mine out of context.

Comment: thx. I tried it with my e-mail adress instead of Jeremy@stackoverflow.com but it did not work. There was no Searchfolder visible in my outlook. I think it still creates the searchfolder in the mailboxworker account not in the one the email is from. 
And also the searchfolder was empty. It did not find any mails.